# Instagram API Get Media Comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have my own Instagram Access Token. How can I read the comments on my Media?

I tried to use the Instagram graph API but it gives me an error.

Documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/instagram-media/comments/

Endpoint - [https://graph.facebook.com/{my-media-id}/comments](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bmy-media-id%7D/comments)

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 190,
        "fbtrace_id": "AZFkVLSyEpT8lSkHT-47_CF"
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you can access data through graph API only if your instagram account is a business account/creator account. If you have one of them, then below is the endpoint to use:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{media-id}?fields=comments](https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/%7Bmedia-id%7D?fields=comments)

go through the below doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview

and make sure you have those permissions added to your access token before you run the endpoint.